# How do I build an an expression using ADF expression language to dynamically generate date in yyyymmdd format for a speciific time zone?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to do something relatively straightforward please help I'm stuck
Given today's date is 02 May, 2021 in my current timezone (Pacific Standard Time), build the string 20210502 (yyyymmdd format) dynamically.

What is the simplest way to do this in ADF? I tried following but returns error invalid expression:

```
@substring(formatString(getutcdate()),0,8)
```

I'm also not sure how to make it flexible so I can enter a different timezone if I want like Pacific Standard Time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timezone variable and pass that value to [convertFromUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#convertfromutc) or [convertTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#converttimezone) function. And you can choose format as you need. Here is the [format specifiers list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#table-of-format-specifiers).

You can follow this:

[image]

expression:`@replace(split(convertFromUtc(utcnow(),variables('timezone'),'u'),' ')[0],'-','')`
[image]

Output:
[image]